# I have a problem with elif statement and else statement and dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, error-handling, printing

The Code

```
men = {1111111111: 'Amal', 2222222222: 'Mohammed', 3333333333: 'Khadijah', 4444444444: 'Abdullah', 5555555555: 'Rawan',
       6666666666: 'Faisal', 7777777777: 'Layla'}


def mo():
    r1 = input('Please Enter The Number: ')
    r = int(r1)
    if r in men:
        print(men[r])
    elif len(str(r)) > 10:
        print('This is invalid number')
    elif len(str(r)) < 10:
        print('This is invalid number')
    elif r not in men:
        print('Sorry, the number is not found')
    else:
        print('This is invalid number')
```

what I want is that the console print 'This is invalid number' if i have entered any data type in the console except integer but error show up in the console page

OutPut

```
Please Enter The Number: d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\walee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    mo()
  File "C:\Users\walee\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 7, in mo
    r = int(r1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu4Al.png)
[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzvp7.png)

Comment: You are passing a string character `'d'` to the `int` function. What happens when you do `int('d')`?

Comment: elif len(str(r)) > 10:  and elif len(str(r)) < 10: can be not equal 10 (!=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `str.isdigit()` to do this. This function returns a boolean which is `True` when the string is made only out of numbers and `False` otherwise. Here's the code:

```py
def mo():
    r1 = input('Please Enter The Number: ')
    if not r1.isdigit():
        print("This is invalid number")
    else:
        r = int(r1)
        if r in men:
            print(men[r])
        elif len(str(r)) > 10:
            print('This is invalid number')
        elif len(str(r)) < 10:
            print('This is invalid number')
        elif r not in men:
            print('Sorry, the number is not found')
        else:
            print('This is invalid number')
```

So, first check whether the input is a number. If it isn't, print that the input is invalid and stop excuting the code, in order to prevent the program from crashing anyway. If it is a number, continue with the rest of the code.

However, I noticed that your code can be simplified into the following:

```py
def mo():
    r1 = input('Please Enter The Number: ')
    if not r1.isdigit() or len(r1)!=10:
        print('This is invalid number')
    else:
        r = int(r1)
        if r in men:
            print(men[r])
        else:
            print('Sorry, the number is not found')
```

This code works in the following way:

First, it checks whether the input is a number and its length is equal to 10 ( or, its length is not bigger and not smaller than 10). Then it converts the input into a number and checks whether the number is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try catch block here to catch the errors. You will either want to get a different user input if it is invalid, or just exit the program.

```py
try:
  r = int(r1)
except:
  print("This is invalid number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input statement in a `while True` loop.  Break out of the loop if they enter a number.

```
while True:
    r1 = input("Enter the number: ")
    if r1.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid number, please try again")

r1 = int(r1)
# ... continue with rest of the code
```